# React.memo inside nested component never calls areEqual, always re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I bumped across a curiosity of where React.memo behaves as expected today.

It seems that React.memo doesn't work in nested functional components, but does work in the components main return and in nested functions that return a React.memo component.

Is this intended behaviour or is there another way to make React.memo work with nested functional components?

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-bhaskara-kbnlg?file=/src/memoTest.js:0-451

```js
const MemoTestBase = ({ name, counter }) => {
  console.log("rendering", name);
  return (
    <div className="">
      <p>
        {name}: {counter}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  const isEqual = prevProps.name === nextProps.name;

  if (isEqual) {
    console.log("stopping", prevProps.name);
  }

  return isEqual;
}

const MemoTest = React.memo(MemoTestBase, areEqual);


const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function funOne() {
    return <MemoTest name="inside function" counter={counter} />;
  }

  const ComponentOne = () => {
    return <MemoTest name="inside component" counter={counter} />;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React.memo render test</h1>
      <p>Count: {counter}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Count + 1</button>
      <hr />
      <p>Memo tests</p>
      <MemoTest name="root" counter={counter} /> {/* works! */}
      <ComponentOne /> {/* doesn't work */}
      {ComponentOne()} {/* works! */}
      {funOne()} {/* works! */}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Define doesn't work?

Comment: never calls areEqual, always re-renders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the `MemoTest` and `ComponentOne` code from `JSX` to `React.createElement` counter part.
Also added a `useEffect` with `[]` dependency array inside `MemoTest` which signifies **initial component mount** and calls a **cleanup function** on **component unmount**. This will let you differentiate between the `Component()` call and `React.createElement(Component)` call.

The code :-

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;



const MemoTestBase = ({ name, counter }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounting");
    return () => console.log("unmounting");
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="">
      <p>
        {name}: {counter}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  const isEqual = prevProps.name === nextProps.name;

  if (isEqual) {
  }

  return isEqual;
}

const MemoTest = React.memo(MemoTestBase, areEqual);

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  
const ComponentOne = () => {
  return React.createElement(MemoTest,{name:"inside component", counter});
};

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React.memo render test</h1>
      <p>Count: {counter}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Count + 1</button>
      <hr />
      <p>Memo tests</p>
      {React.createElement(ComponentOne)} {/* doesn't work */}
      {ComponentOne()} {/* works! */}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Now, deriving from @Shubham's answer, a new `Component` function is created every time when your `counter` changes which causes a **re-render** of `App`.

Now a new reference of `Component` is passed to `React.createElement(...)` on **re-render** which mean's the old one is **unmounted** and a new one is **mounted**. This also means the same for it's **children**. The **child** here is `MemoTest` and so you will be able to see the **unmounted and mounted logs** being triggered from inside it. `React.memo(..)` is a `render` optimization and not something which can memoize across `re-mount` of **components**.

For the `Component()` call, there is no `React.createElement` in the picture itself so there is no **unmount** of `Component` and thus none for `MemoTest` and so `React.memo(..)` works as expected.

Moving `Component` outside of `App` as a separate function ensures that it's reference doesn't change on each `render` of `App` as it was happening earlier and so calling `React.createElement(Component)` doesn't cause a **unmount** and **mount** on each **render** of `App` which ultimately ensures that `React.createElement(MemoTest)` only tries to cause a `re-render` of `MemoTest` which doesn't work due to `React.memo(...)`.

Comment: So calling the function like `<ComponentOne />` triggers `React.createElement` which then binds to a reference of the function which is a problem as it is being rewritten on every `App` render. As opposed to calling it like `{ComponentOne()` which React won't interpret as it's own element, hence never triggers `React.createElement` and sees the function call as just another part of the `App` component? Am I understanding that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are defining ComponentOne inside your component. So when React tries to re-render it sees that the ComponentOne Reference in previous re-render was different than the one in the current re-render and hence this component is remounted. Hence the memo doesn't work

However when you call it like a function, it returns the same instance of `MemoTest`, so a re-render is supposed to happen which is prevented by `memo` as props do not change

To make it work like you have define it currently, you should move the functional component definition out of the App Component

```js
const MemoTestBase = ({ name, counter }) => {
  console.log("rendering", name);
  return (
    <div className="">
      <p>
        {name}: {counter}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  const isEqual = prevProps.name === nextProps.name;

  if (isEqual) {
    console.log("stopping", prevProps.name);
  }

  return isEqual;
}

const MemoTest = React.memo(MemoTestBase, areEqual);


const ComponentOne = ({counter}) => {
  return <MemoTest name="inside component" counter={counter} />;
};

const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function funOne() {
    return <MemoTest name="inside function" counter={counter} />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React.memo render test</h1>
      <p>Count: {counter}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Count + 1</button>
      <hr />
      <p>Memo tests</p>
      <MemoTest name="root" counter={counter} /> {/* works! */}
      <ComponentOne counter={counter}/> {/* doesn't work */}
      {ComponentOne({counter})} {/* works! */}
      {funOne()} {/* works! */}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```